# Creating table with a foreign key not working?

Tags: mysql

Creating table with a foreign key not working?
trying to create this table and for some reason it doesnt work i keep getting an error message.

My code is:

```
create table lecturers (
    lectid int not null,
    fname varchar(34),
    lname varchar(34),
    unitid int,
    primary key (lectid),
    constraint unitFK foreign key (unitid) references units(unitid);
```

other table :

```
mysql> create table units 
( unitid int primary key, 
unit_name varchar(34) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is missing parenthesis in create table statement for lecturers table

try this

```
  create table lecturers (
    lectid int not null,
    fname varchar(34),
    lname varchar(34),
    unitid int,
    primary key (lectid),
    constraint unitFK foreign key (unitid) references units(unitid));
```